# Are we allowed to publish Excel JS add-in to Microsoft App Source, if a user must log in to it with a side-service credentials?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, office-store

I'm in progress of reading the [Commercial marketplace certification policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/marketplace/certification-policies), and the question that has arisen is the next. Are we allowed to publish our free to download add-in if a user to use it must log in with credentials from the other service? We must check his credentials after he downloads the add-in, but before he starts using our add-in (because of the licenses policy).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution